# In a DataFrame grouped by 2 fields, calculate difference between rows n and n-1 from 2nd grouping field inside the 1st grouping field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataFrame (subset of many areas and years, not the same years range per area) :

| Area | Year | Food Aid (kg) | Population | Malnutrition | Malnutrition rate (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 2013 | 128238 | 32269.589 | 8600.00000 | 26.65000 |
|  | 2014 | 57214 | 33370.79400 | 8800.00000 | 26.37000 |
| Algeria | 2013 | 35234 | 38140.13300 | 1300.00000 | 3.41000 |
|  | 2014 | 18980 | 38923.69200 | 1300.00000 | 3.34000 |
|  | 2015 | 17424 | 39728.02500 | 1300.00000 | 3.27000 |
|  | 2016 | 9476 | 40551.39200 | 1300.00000 ​ | 3.21000 |

Created with a groupby from a dataset which contained data for each country and each available year ; then added the calculated row :

```py
df.groupby(['Area', 'Year']).agg(
    {
        'Food Aid (kg)' : 'sum',
        'Population' : lambda x: x.iloc[0],
        'Malnutrition': lambda x: x.iloc[0]
    })

df['Malnutrition rate (%)'] = round(((df.loc[:,'Malnutrition'] / df.loc[:,'Population']))*100,2)
```

I would like to add 2 aggregated columns as such. For a country, given a year N, the percentage of evolution since N-1 of :

- Food Aid
- Malnutrition

Something like :

| Area | Year | Food Aid (kg) | Population | Malnutrition | Malnutrition rate (%) | Food Aid evolution (%) | Malnutrition rate evolution (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 2013 | 128238 | 32269.589 | 8600.00000 | 26.65000 | --- | --- |
|  | 2014 | 57214 | 33370.79400 | 8800.00000 | 26.37000 | -55.38 | -1.051 |
| Algeria | 2013 | 35234 | 38140.13300 | 1300.00000 | 3.41000 | --- | --- |
|  | 2014 | 18980 | 38923.69200 | 1300.00000 | 3.34000 | -46.132 | -2.053 |
|  | 2015 | 17424 | 39728.02500 | 1300.00000 | 3.27000 | -8.198 | -2.096 |
|  | 2016 | 9476 | 40551.39200 | 1300.00000 ​ | 3.21000 | -45.615 | -1.835 |

I'm quite a beginner in Pandas. I've tried several things without much success. For example, this loop I'm not sure how to use to make things work:

```
for key, value in df:
    # key is an array of grouped keys. Examples: (Afghanistan, 2013), (Afghanistan, 2014)
    # value is a Series of the various cols for the current row
```

**Question**: in a dataframe grouped by 2 fields: how to add a new column which contains a calculation between the rows n and n-1 of the 2nd grouping field, inside the 1st grouping field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pct_change`:

```
new_cols = {'Food Aid (kg)': 'Food Aid evolution (%)',
            'Malnutrition rate (%)': 'Malnutrition rate evolution (%)'}

out = df.join(df.groupby('Area')[['Food Aid (kg)', 'Malnutrition rate (%)']]
                .pct_change().mul(100).rename(columns=new_cols))
```

```
>>> out[new_cols.values()]

                  Food Aid evolution (%)  Malnutrition rate evolution (%)
Area        Year
Afghanistan 2013                     NaN                              NaN
            2014              -55.384519                        -1.050657
Algeria     2013                     NaN                              NaN
            2014              -46.131577                        -2.052786
            2015               -8.198103                        -2.095808
            2016              -45.615243                        -1.834862
```

Comment: Straight forward example. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Look at `pct_change`

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg({'Food Aid (kg)': 'pct_change',
                         'Malnutrition rate (%)': 'pct_change'})*100

             Food Aid (kg)  Malnutrition rate (%)
Area                                             
Afghanistan            NaN                    NaN
Afghanistan     -55.384519              -1.050657
Algeria                NaN                    NaN
Algeria         -46.131577              -2.052786
Algeria          -8.198103              -2.095808
Algeria         -45.615243              -1.834862
```

This assumes that the years you want to compare are ordered and sequential

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I should have looked at the aggregation functions!